# Pass parameters to new window [Titanium]

Tags: windows, file, parameters, titanium

In the following code, I need to pass the `text` variable from app.js to app_flip.js and display it over there. How can I do this ?

```
**In app.js**
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'white'});

button.addEventListener('click,function(e){
 Ti.include('app_flip.js');
});
var text = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text:"hello" });
win.add(text);

**In app_flip.js**
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'white'});
```

Comment: This is the most beaten topic for titanium if you have searched a little bit you have find dozens of links as i am going to paste here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098442/titanium-passing-variable-to-new-window http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132078/passing-variable-between-window http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119798/how-do-i-pass-variables-from-one-view-to-another http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/71401/how-do-i-pass-variables-from-one-page-to-another http://sushmapandey.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/passing-parameters-from-currentwindow-to-the-new-window-i

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new window using the following method
**app.js**

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url : 'app_flip.js',
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        _customProperty : 'Value of the property'
    });

    win.open();
});
```

**app_flip.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var _customProperty = win._customProperty;
alert(_customProperty); //Will display Value of the property
```

You can use [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/86681/passing-data-between-window) as a reference